# Bessel's function

Tags: reference-request, special-functions, integration

I read that $\int\limits_0^1 xJ_n(j_{na}x) J_n(j_{nb}x) dx={1\over 2}\delta_{ab}[J_n'(j_{na})]^2$, where $j_{na},j_{nb}$ are zeros of $J_n$, the Bessel function of the $n$th degree. Is there a simple proof for this? Thanks.

Comment: Where did you read this ?

Comment: @Sasha: On quite a few websites talking about Bessel functions. This demonstrates the orthogonality and helps us normalize... But I have't found a website that gives a proof of this. They tend to say "it can be shown that..." I have tried proving it myself, starting with the Bessel equations. I have managed to show that if $a\neq b$ tgen tge integral vanishes, but I can't show the $a=b$ case. Thought I might let $a=b+\epsilon$ Then take limit as epsilon tends to 0...

Comment: I'm tempted to think this can be proven as a special case of the orthogonality result in Sturm-Liouville theory: [url]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm–Liouville_theory[\url]. I'll leave the details to someone else though.

Comment: @Ragib I suspect that the reason why the URL you posted isn't working is that there's an en-dash in the title.  I also suspect that a Wikipedia page with the same title but a hyphen rather than an en-dash is a redirect page that directs to the article whose title has an en-dash.  Let's try it: [url]en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm-Liouville_theory[/url]

Comment: Typo.  I'll try again: [url]en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm-Liouville_theory[\url]

Comment: @Michael: `[Sturm-Liouville](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm-Liouville_theory)` produces [Sturm-Liouville](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm-Liouville_theory). They use Markdown here, not BBCode. :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I need to start remembering this!

Answer (score 3):

Using Mellin convolution [technique](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?_=1320419391830&fp=1&i=integrate%28x%20BesselJ%28n,a%2ax%29%20BesselJ%28n,%20b%2ax%29,%20%7Bx,0,1%7D%29&incTime=true), the following integral is available in closed form, assuming $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$:
$$
   \int_0^1 x J_n\left( \alpha x \right) J_n \left( \beta x \right) \mathrm{d} x = 
      \frac{\beta  J_n(\alpha ) J_{n-1}(\beta )-\alpha  J_{n-1}(\alpha ) J_n(\beta)}{
        \alpha^2-\beta ^2}     
$$
From this, it follows immediately that if $\alpha = j_{na}$ and $\beta = j_{nb}$ and $a \not= b$, the integral vanishes.

Taking the limit of $\beta \to \alpha$:
$$
    \int_0^1 x J_n\left( \alpha x \right) J_n \left( \alpha x \right) \mathrm{d} x = 
       \frac{1}{2} \left( J_n^2(\alpha) - J_{n+1}(\alpha) J_{n-1}(\alpha) \right)
$$
When $\alpha = j_{na}$ the first term vanishes. 
Using the fact that:
$$
    J_n^\prime(x) = \frac{n}{x} J_n(x) - J_{n+1}(x) = J_{n-1}(x) - \frac{n}{x} J_n(x)
$$
and setting $x = j_{na}$ we recover the identity you encountered.

---

Actually, I am wrong about need to use Mellin convolution technique. The integrand [has](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=x+BesselJ%5Bn%2Ca%2ax%5D+BesselJ%5Bn%2C+b%2ax%5D&random=false) a closed-form anti-derivative:
$$
    \int x J_n\left( \alpha x \right) J_n \left( \beta x \right) \mathrm{d} x = 
   \frac{\beta  x J_n(x \alpha ) J_{n-1}(x \beta )-\alpha  x J_{n-1}(x \alpha ) J_n(x \beta
   )}{\alpha ^2-\beta ^2}
$$
which is easy to check by differentiation.

After that the definition integral is obtained using the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Thanks, Sasha! Is there an analytic way to show the 1st integral?